# AVG and COUNT functions are not giving proper result in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have following query and I am trying to display members in the order where members with highest average rating will be displayed first, if more than one members have same average rating then highest number of rating will be considered.

Here,
Member A has been rated by 3 visitors and average rating value is 5 while
Member B has been rated by 2 visitors and average rating value is 5

So according to below query, Member A should display first because he has 5 average rating and rated by 3 persons while Member B should display on second position.

But Member B is displaying first and Member A is displaying second so this is problem. Please let me know what wrong I am doing in query.

```
SELECT m.*,mc.* 
FROM      t_member m
LEFT JOIN tr_member_category mc ON m.memberpkid=mc.memberpkid
LEFT JOIN tr_comment c 
          ON m.memberpkid=c.memberpkid 
             AND c.approved='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
WHERE m.visible='YES' AND m.approved='YES' 
       AND m.gender='FEMALE' AND mc.archivecatpkid=1 
GROUP BY m.memberpkid
ORDER BY avg(c.ratingvalue) DESC, COUNT(c.ratingvalue) DESC
```

Thank you very much in advance,
KRA

Comment: Are you sure that there's a one-to-one relationship between members and categories? If not, your results are [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: What datatype is ratingvalue? Int or some floating value? What are the rating values for A and B?

Comment: ratingvalue datatype is bigint(20)
A has 3 rating values and they are 5, 5 and 5 (so average is 5)
A has 2 rating values and they are 5 and 5 (so average is 5)

Comment: I am sorry but exactly what do you want to say by one-to-one relationship between members and categories? Please explain in details so I can reply properly. This will be very helpful for me.

Comment: See this blog post to understand what Mark is trying to say: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html (essential the results of a group by that does not group by all non-aggregate columns is "random")

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN instead of inner joins?

Comment: If you add `, avg(c.ratingvalue) AS avg, COUNT(c.ratingvalue) AS cnt ` in the SELECT clause, what do you have when running the query?

Answer (score 0):

Move the AVG and COUNT functions out of the ORDER clause, into the SELECT clause. Give them a good name and then order on those.
i.e.

```
SELECT m.*, mc.*, AVG(c.ratingvalue) AS average_rating, COUNT(c.ratingvalue) AS number_of_ratings
FROM      t_member m
LEFT JOIN tr_member_category mc ON m.memberpkid=mc.memberpkid
LEFT JOIN tr_comment c 
      ON m.memberpkid=c.memberpkid 
         AND c.approved='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
WHERE m.visible='YES' AND m.approved='YES' 
   AND m.gender='FEMALE' AND mc.archivecatpkid=1 
GROUP BY m.memberpkid
ORDER BY average_rating DESC, number_of_ratings DESC
```

EDIT: remember that an aggregate function returns a value. If you put them in an ORDER BY clause, it reads "order by this value", as opposed to "order by this **column**". Keep that in mind whilst writing SQL.

Comment: Hello, Maarten Jacobs

Thank you for your help. I did what you said above and I also understand now what you were saying about aggregate function. But unluckily it doesn't solve my issue and giving same result like before. Can you help further to resolve this issue?